# What is Mathematical formulation of Holographic principle?

Tags: string-theory, holographic-principle

What is Mathematical formulation of [Holographic principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holographic_principle)

> The holographic principle is a property of quantum gravity and string theories which states that the description of a volume of space can be thought of as encoded on a boundary to the region—preferably a light-like boundary like a gravitational horizon.

Comment: The WP article you linked to gives a reference to "a precise string-theory interpretation by Leonard Susskind," but says that "Cosmological holography has not been made mathematically precise, partly because the cosmological horizon has a finite area and grows with time," giving two more references. Are you asking for a presentation of the ideas in the Susskind paper? At what level?

Comment: Asking about the mathematical formulation of the holographic principle is rather specific and by no means "too broad" ... I am personally interested to see a clear cut answer here too!

Comment: beware about the "realizations" of the holographic principle, they are in general just interpreted as being realizations. Also, the holographic principle is not proved to be a "property" of quantum gravity as it is not linked in an unambiguous way to quantum gravity (as a full theory). It is simply a conjecture and widely overrated too

Answer (score 9):

It is maybe an underappreciated fact that the old relation between the 2d [Wess-Zumino-Witten model](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Wess-Zumino-Witten+model) on a Lie group $G$ and the 3d $G$-[Chern-Simons theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Chern-Simons%20theory) is an example of the [holographic principle](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/holographic+principle). See for instance

- Sergei Gukov, Emil Martinec, Gregory Moore, Andrew Strominger, *Chern-Simons Gauge Theory and the AdS(3)/CFT(2) Correspondence* ([arXiv:hep-th/0403225](http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/hep-th/0403225))

and see on the nLab at *[AdS3-CFT2 and CS-WZW correspondence](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/AdS3-CFT2+and+CS-WZW+correspondence)* for more pointers.

Now the [2dWZW/3dCS correspondence](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/AdS3-CFT2+and+CS-WZW+correspondence) is, to a considerable degree of detail, a mathematical theorem. At the heart this says that the [geometric quantization](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+quantization) (which is the mathematically precise formulation of quantization) of 3d CS over a (punctured) surface $\Sigma$ yields the spaces of states of 3d CS over $\Sigma$ for each choice of [polarization](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/polarization) of the theory as a projectively flat bundle -- the [Hitchin connection](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hitchin+connection) -- over the moduli space of conformal structures on $\Sigma$, and that this are the spaces of conformal blocks of the 2d WZW model with worldvolume $\Sigma$.

For a review of what exactly this means a good place to start is around p. 30 of

- Krzysztof Gawędzki, *Conformal field theory: a case study* ([arXiv:hep-th/9904145](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9904145))

Another maybe underappreciated fact is that in

- Edward Witten, *AdS/CFT Correspondence And Topological Field Theory* JHEP 9812:012, 1998, ([arXiv:hep-th/9812012](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/7d%20Chern-Simons%20theory#Witten98))

it is argued that also [AdS5-CFT4 holography](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/AdS-CFT#AdS5CFT4) as well as [AdS7-CFT6 holography](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/AdS-CFT#AdS7CFT6), at least, are all controled by just the *higher Chern-Simons term* on the gravity side, at least as far as the conformal blocks on the CFT side are concerned.

Notably this means by AdS7-CFT6 holography that the [6d (2,0)-superconformal QFT](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/6d%20%282,0%29-superconformal%20QFT) on the [M5-brane](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/M5-brane) is determined by the [7d Chern-Simons theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/7d%20Chern-Simons%20theory) inside the 11d Chern-Simons term of [11-dimensional supergravity](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/11-dimensional%20supergravity) after [KK-reduction](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/KK-reduction) on a 4-sphere.

Indeed, this is how Witten proposed to capture the M5-brane theory in

- Edward Witten, *Five-Brane Effective Action In M-Theory* J. Geom. Phys.22:103-133,1997 ([arXiv:hep-th/9610234](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9610234))

(there for the simple special case of the abelian theory on a single M5): one can formalize what it means to apply [geometric quantization](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric%20quantization) in codimension 1 to the [7d Chern-Simons theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/7d%20Chern-Simons%20theory) to obtain its space of states, and according to Witten's argument this is, holographically, the space of conformal blocks of the 6d conformal field theory on the 5-brane.

It was the desire to give a fully mathematically precise formulation of this "holographic quantization" of the single M5-brane that led to the seminal article

- Mike Hopkins, Isadore Singer, *[Quadratic Functions in Geometry, Topology, and M-Theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Quadratic+Functions+in+Geometry%2C+Topology%2C+and+M-Theory)*, J. Differential Geom. Volume 70, Number 3 (2005), 329-452

maybe one of the high points of deep mathematics motivated by or found in string/M-theory.

(Incidentally, the abelian 7d Chern-Simons term that Witten considered in the above article is well known to receive quantum corrections from a Green-Schwarz mechanism in 11d sugra and from the "flux quantization condition". The full 7d Chern-Simons term in 11d sugram KK-reduced on the 4-sphere is that of a *nonabelian* Chern-Simons theory. We wrote that out as an extended prequantum field theory in the articles [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/7d+Chern-Simons+theory#ReferencesNonabelianTheories). It is natural to expect that the holographic dual of this complete nonabelian Chern-Simons term of 11d sugra is the 6d-theory on the 5-brane with its *nonabelian* 2-form field. But this remains to be analyzed.)

In order to find more instances of mathematically precise aspects of holography, it also serves to go *down* in dimension from [WZW2/CS3](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/AdS3-CFT2+and+CS-WZW+correspondence) to the holographic relation between point particle quantum mechanics and the 2d topological string.

A semi-formalization of this is Kontsevich's [formal deformation quantization](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/formal%20deformation%20quantization) of any Poisson manifold, which was later understood in

- Alberto Cattaneo, Giovanni Felder, *Poisson sigma models and deformation quantization*, Mod. Phys. Lett. A 16, 179–190 (2001) ([hep-th/0102208](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0102208))

to be secretly the 3-point function of the open topological string propagating on the Poisson manifold as given by the [Poisson sigma-model](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Poisson%20sigma-model).

Now Kontsevich's formula is rigorous mathematics, and the interpretation by Cattaneo-Felder in terms of [BV-quantization](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/BV-quantization) is written at the level of rigour at least of mathematical physics. Therefore I would regard this as one more mathematically precise incarnation of the holographic principle.

Notice that there is a slight variant of this holographic quantization of 1d quantum mechanics in terms of 2d topological string given by Gukov-Witten's [quantization via the A-model](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quantization%20via%20the%20A-model), where the particle with phase space a symplectic manifold is quantized as the boundary theory of the topological A-model string (a limit of the topological Poisson model string).

Recently my student Joost Nuiten has described a rigorous *non-perturbative* version of this holographic quantization of particles with phase space a Poisson manifold as the boundary theory of the non-perturbative Poisson sigma-model. This is described in the examples section of

- Joost Nuiten, *[Cohomological quantization of local prequantum boundary field theory](http://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/master%20thesis%20Nuiten)*, thesis, Utrecht 2013

He also describes other rigorous instances of holographic quantization. For instance he indicates how the heterotic string is quantized as the boundary theory of the M2-brane ending on an "M9-brane" heterotic boundary spacetime of an 11d Hořava-Witten spacetime. A survey of this is also in the examples-section in the nLab entry on *[motivic quantization](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/motivic%20quantization)*.

The mechanism described there I suspect gives a general mathematical rigorous formalization of holography. But this needs to be further explored.